# Save RTSP stream locally, then display local copy "live"

Tags: php, html, stream, ip, rtsp

I have a vivotek IP camera in a remote location using a wireless internet provider with limited bandwidth. Because of the limited bandwidth and the possibility of having hundreds of people trying to access it at one time, I need an alternate solution than accessing the stream directly.

My idea was that I could stream it to my webhost via RTSP and save it locally onto the webhost. Then in the webpage just play the local copy. This should limit the connections to the IP camera to just one (from the webhost) however still play a "live" copy for the viewers (doesnt have to be exactly live, as long as its some type of stream).

I will be limited on the things I can do as it will only be a plain webhost used (as opposed to VPS) so no root access or ability to install software or anything like that. Only FTP, PHP, MySQL, etc.

From the IP camera I can either get an RTSP stream or a motion jpeg. But the final display on the webpage needs to be cross platform (I dont think IE supports motion jpeg, and firefox doesnt support rtsp if i remember correctly). It might be ideal if it can be trasncoded to AVI or something along those lines and then embedded into the page, but the problem again is im limited on the webhost side.

My biggest problem is I've never ever done anything like this so I'm baffled where to even begin... or if its even remotely possible.

Im open to all suggestions as its something that needs to get done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was suggested to me to use http://www.ustream.tv/. 
Personally I couldn't get it working, but I'm throwing it out there in case it helps someone else.

If a better answer turns up then I will definitely take a look as I was never able to finish this project.